# How to pass string to SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

I want to pass String into my SMSReceiver.
But I got following error.

> Unable to start receiver net.learn2develop.LocationTracker.SMSReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

here is my activity that I want to pass string here:

```
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String p=pass.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LocationTrackerActivity.this, SMSReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("string", p);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
    });
```

and here I get the string:

```
 void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {        
        //---get the SMS message that was received---
      //Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("string"),                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String user_message = intent.getStringExtra("string");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str="";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        senderTel = "";

        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            if (i==0) {
                //---get the sender address/phone number---
                senderTel = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            } 
            //---get the message body---
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();                 
        }

        if (str.startsWith(user_message)) {
            //---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
            lm = (LocationManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

            //---request location updates---
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                    60000, 
                    1000, 
                    locationListener);

            //---abort the broadcast; SMS messages won’t be broadcasted---
            this.abortBroadcast();
        }
    }                         
}
```

I search but noting helpful.all my attempt got this error.
any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you trying to send a plain `String` to a `BroadcastReceiver` that's meant for SMS messages? It's not going to work like that.

Comment: Base on message the user received I want to identify the user location

Comment: If you will look at the code in the Receiver, you will notice that it's expecting the data it receives to be in a very particular format. You're not going to be able to test it by sending it a simple `String`. If you want to test an SMS Receiver, test it with SMS.

Comment: not clear for me:-(

Comment: This is your problem:
`Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];`
You did not supply 'pdus' in your intent, so it will be null. On the next line, you are trying to get the length of it, causing an NPE. Furthermore I agree with @MikeM.; If you want to test something that is called an SMSReceiver, use an SMS to test it

Comment: What does this (use an SMS to test it )mean?you mean that send SMS to test the code?